# Find the number of zeros of $f(z) = 2 + z^4 + e^{iz}$

Tags: complex-analysis

1. In the set $\{z : |z| ≤ r,\Im z ≥ 0\}$ for any $r \gt 2$.

Can someone please help me out?

I used rouche's theorem that $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ both have zeros of $4$

However, I am not sure what to do after....

Comment: Please someone help me, I spent too much time on this I need to know this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us choose a function $g(z)=z^4+2$. Now we need to verify that on the boundary $|f(z)-g(z)|<|g(z)|$.  This is true on the boundary $r=2$. Since $|e^{iz}|<2$ and $|z^4+2|>14$. Now we have to show that the inequality is true even on the real line.$|e^{iz}|=1$ whereas $z^4+2 \ge2$. So by Rouches theorem it has same number of zeroes as $z^4+2$ which is two.

Comment: the answer is actually 2....I am not sure why

Comment: This polynomial has 4 zeros, all in the disc of radius r, and exactly two of them are in the upper half plane (angles π/4
and 3π/4). Thus our function has two zeros in the indicated set.

Comment: @HyunminJung Jung thanks for pointing that out I have edited my answer

Comment: You are right but the part I am not sure about is e^iz, why do we perform inequality separately for e^iz, I thought f(z) is 2+z^4+e^iz then g(z) is z^4+2, then if you take the modulus you are left with modulus of e^iz < modulus of z^4

Comment: why would checking boundary of 2 help?? I mean r > 2 so it we set r < 2 find its zero, if 2 since polynomial has degree 4 we can conclude r>2 will have 2 zeros right?

Comment: Because next question was to find zeros in the upper half plane and no condition r>2 given....how is it two shouldn't it be four...???

Comment: Okay I got it but its for any r < 2 why do we take r = 2 to be our boundary

Comment: @HyunminJung We can take any $r>2$ we will obtain the inequality $|f(z)-g(z)|<|g(z)|$ actually for that I had to strengthen the inequality on $|e^{iz}|$ that is $|e^{iz}|=|e^{-y}|<2$ since $y>0$